# Problem with news webpart in a Hub site with filter on managed property

Tags: managed-property, hub-site, news-webpart

I would really like that some of you test my same scenario and confirm that it is by design (and possibly WHY it is this way).

- Hub Site with 2-3 site associated News post with an additional column
  (managed metadata from the term store)
- News web part on the hub site with "all sites in the hub" and filter of Managed property (correctly crawled) that only news with the term "yes" can be shown on it

What happens to me is that if I use EQUAL YES it shows nothing, but if I switch it to contains it picks up all the YES news posts.

Is there an explanation for this?

Edited to add: I have now done 2 tests and they both came out this way. In both cases I went to see in the search schema and noticed that my managed property ( owstaxId**** where **** is the name of the column) is not there at all, is this normal? I search for the name of the column, owstaxId**** and it does not return this item in the Managed properties and in the crawled properties